# How to use ffmpeg to replace part of an image with a transparent polygon

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to replace part of an png image with a transparent polygon. I have tried to use the ffmpeg tool in mac terminal.

I have tried to following command. But this draw a black rectangle and not a transparent one: `ffmpeg -i hemma_bil_2200_crop.png -filter_complex "crop=1344:1200:50:50, drawbox=50:50:100:200:#00000000@1:fill" output.png`

1. I aim to get it transparent and not black
2. I would like to draw a polygon instead of a rectangle if possible. The polygon I would like, is a rectangle with the right side somewhat sloping i.e. the base should be somewhat longer than the top.

Comment: Have you tried Imagemagick?

Comment: 2. - do you mean just a right trapezoid?

Comment: It looks like your trying to hide a specific part of the image from view. This is a breach of the copyright law if the image does not belong to you. Contact the image owner and let them know that you intend to make altercations to their image first.

Comment: It's my own images I create from a 3d tool, but I would like to hide part of it to blend several images together with another tool, to make a composite image. I'm doing an interactive floor plan for a home automation project making different rooms light up when the real life lights are turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [generic equation filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#geq)

1. rectangle

   ```
   ffmpeg -i in.png -lavfi "
   format=rgba,
   geq=lum='p(X,Y)'
   :a='if(between(X,100,150),0,255)+if(between(Y,200,250),0,255)'
   " -frames:v 1 out.png
   ```
2. right side sloped

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "in.png" -lavfi "
   format=rgba,
   geq=lum='p(X,Y)'
   :a='if(between(X,100,150+(Y-200)/3),0,255)+if(between(Y,200,250),0,255)'
   " -frames:v 1 out.png
   ```

Comment: That seem to solve the first question. Do you know how to modify the transparent area from a rectangle into a polygon. I would need the right side to be sloping:
`-\
`

Comment: Spot on, great and thank you!